# *ngFor is not working with dynamic values

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

Working on some array projects but Stuck on point where *ngFor did't accept dynamic value provided by another `*ngFor`.

```
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Subject</th>
    <th colspan="4" *ngFor='#category of json.category_name'>{{category}}</th>
    <th colspan="4">Overall</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <div *ngFor="#category of json.category_name">
      <th *ngFor="#fa of json.total_fa.category">{{fa}}</th>  //Not Working
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here in the commented line i want to provide `json.total_fa.category` where this `category` is coming from another `*ngFor`  which is declared just above. but getting no result it seems angular try to find out `json.total_fa.category` itself which is not present.

but i want to load `json.total_fa_term1` (which is first index from the category). how can i achive this.

2. Can i use more than one *ngFor on same HTML component ?
3. sometimes *ngFor and *ngIf is not working properly while embed on the same element why ?

here is my [workground demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xEL1rITGKG7BAXgVwYIN?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.total_fa[category]` instead of `.total_fa.category` otherwise you will try to access a property with name `category`:

```
<div *ngFor="#category of json.category_name">
  <th *ngFor="#fa of json.total_fa[category]">{{fa}}</th>
</div>
```

See the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/v08AdzNsR4GHMlZWQNsR?p=preview.

Comment: wow that works fine but bit problem is there. the `<th>` does not work properly i dont know why as per expectation all `<th>` should be in the single row. how to achive this ?

Comment: can i use more than one `*ngFor` in one element ?

Comment: I think you should leverage pipes rather than `ngFor` for your use case. Sure you can have more than one `ngFor`. I updated my forked plunkr to make your sample work: http://plnkr.co/edit/v08AdzNsR4GHMlZWQNsR?p=preview. Feel free to tell me if it corresponds to what you expect ;-)

Comment: i have done with this by some fixed codde but without using pipe here is http://plnkr.co/edit/xEL1rITGKG7BAXgVwYIN?p=preview . is this the correct method not to use pipe in this use case ? btw thnks alot for help.

Comment: Your approach seems correct! I used a pipe previously to flatten the arrays but it wasn't perhaps what you need. Was just a proposal ;-)