# With *ngFor="#var of list", how do I access map[#var]?

Tags: angular

In my template, if I create a local variable with *ngFor, how do I use it as a key to access a map? The template code below raises Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 12 in ...

```
<li *ngFor="#item of my_list">
 <div [class]="my_map[#item]></div>
</li>
```

Furthermore, how do I use #item as an accessor function param?

Is any of this possible at all to use #item without creating a sub-component?

Comment: somewhere similer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/35847244/5043867

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` before the variable name is to declare the variable (similar to `var` in JavaScript) when you want to get the value of the variable, omit the `#`

```ts
<li *ngFor="let item of my_list">
 <div [class]="my_map[item]></div>
</li>
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngFor